# Adobe air APNs remoteNotificationEvent does not act

Tags: air, apple-push-notifications

I use the notice of push using apns using Air 3.6 with `RemoteNotificaitonEvent`.

Although event listening is carried out by `TOKEN`, `NOTIFICATION`, and `STATUS`, and event flies to no listeners.

Would you teach how to solve?

code snippet of the following sites is used as it is.
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/29/push-notifications-support-in-ios/

Comment: can you show us your codes?

Comment: Any error log / message ?

Comment: yes, any error log.even if the dialog of whether to permit the notice of push comes out and it pushes ok, there is no reaction of an event